# How to get models into ember component

Tags: ember.js

I want to build a component to display the tags of an item like on the mac where every tag has its color. Most stuff I read about components say that the component should not excess any model directly. But in this case I had to pass the list of tags for an item and additionally the tag/color combinations. I wonder what will be the ember way to have the tag/color combination in the component without passing it every time I use the component.

In the end I wanna call the component like this

```
{{tag-list tags=item.tags}}
```

The question for me is, how can the component get the color/tag combination model without passing it every time I use the component, cause in this case the view needs to that use the component needs to know this model. This seems a bit odd cause all the view should know is, that there will be a component that will renderer the tags.

Comment: So, your question is the syntax for passing a model into a component? Please add a clear question to your post as it looks more like a statement.

Comment: I wonder what would be the right way to have the Model that holds the color/tag combination in the component without passing them every time I use the component.

Comment: If you don't want to pass the properties every time into the component, I think you should be using a template instead. One of the reason people like to use components is encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're wondering how to pass a model into a component?

```
// if item is just referring to your model
{{tag-list tags=tags}}

// if item is a property in your model
{{tag-list tags=item.tags}}
```

So it appears that it should work just like you hope it well. [See the Ember guide to passing properties into a component](http://emberjs.com/guides/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/). If you're having a problem getting it to work properly, I think there's an error elsewhere in your code.